# bottom overflowed by 42 pixels in a SingleChildScrollView

Tags: dart, flutter

I have used a form inside a  SingleChildScrollView, and everything works fine:

Form  : 
Everything works fine,
[image]

I have used this code

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double stackHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/4;
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child :SafeArea(
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                    begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                    end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                    colors: [const Color(0xFF3023AE), const Color(0xFFC86DD7)])),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  height: stackHeight*2.6,
                  child: IntroViewsFlutter(
                    pages,
                    onTapDoneButton: (){
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                    showSkipButton: false,
                    pageButtonsColor: btnColors,
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                    height: stackHeight*1.4,
                    child: bottomHomePage(),
                    color: pageColor,
                    width: width,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
      ),
      )
    );
```

but when errors appear, this is what happens :

[image]

I have tried many things, I have heard about layoutBuilder, but dont know if it will work for me or there are another solutions that can adapt to runtime events.

UPDATE : 
the problem was coming only of using an expanded inside a column : here we are the code again :

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
            body: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Center (
                child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        gradient: LinearGradient(
                            begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                            end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                            colors: [const Color(0xFF3023AE), const Color(0xFFC86DD7)])),
                    child: Form(
                      key: _formKey,
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 70.0, bottom: 20.0),
                            child: Text(
                              "C'est parti !",
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32, color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
                            child: Container(
                                width: width_textFormField + 15.0,
                                child: Text(
                                  " Avant de commencer, sache que pour utiliser pleinement ta BanKids tu devras demander à tes parents de s'inscrire pour te débloquer toutes les fonctionnalités",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 14,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                )),
                          ),
                          Container(
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Container(
                                    child: Text(
                                      "Client Bank ?",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          color: Colors.white),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Container(
                                      child: Row(
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Text(
                                            "Oui",
                                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                          ),
                                          Radio(
                                            value: 1,
                                            activeColor: Colors.white,
                                            groupValue: _grpVal,
                                            onChanged: _handleRadioValueChange1,
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      )),
                                  Container(
                                      child: Row(
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Text(
                                            "Non",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                color: Colors.white),
                                          ),
                                          Radio(
                                            activeColor: Colors.white,
                                            value: 2,
                                            groupValue: _grpVal,
                                            onChanged: _handleRadioValueChange1,
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      )),
                                ],
                              )),
                          Container(
                            child: Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                customizedTextFormField(
                                    hintText: "Nom",
                                    width: width_textFormField + 10.0,
                                    txtColor: Colors.black),
                                customizedTextFormField(
                                    hintText: "Prénom",
                                    width: width_textFormField + 10.0,
                                    txtColor: Colors.black),
                                customizedTextFormField(
                                    hintText: "Date de Naissance",
                                    width: width_textFormField + 10.0,
                                    txtColor: Colors.black),
                                customizedTextFormField(
                                    hintText: "CIN",
                                    width: width_textFormField + 10.0,
                                    txtColor: Colors.black),
                                customizedTextFormField(
                                    hintText: "Email",
                                    width: width_textFormField + 10.0,
                                    txtColor: Colors.black)
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
                            child: Container(
                              width: width_textFormField,
                              child: Row(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Checkbox(
                                    checkColor: Color(0xFF3023AE),
                                    value: isCheck,
                                    activeColor: Colors.white,
                                    onChanged: _handleCheckBox,
                                  ),
                                  Expanded(
                                    child: Text(
                                      "En continuant l'inscription, je déclare accepter ces conditions d'utilisations ",
                                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          //************ next work
                         Container(
                                  width: 200,
                                  height: 60,
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0,bottom: 8.0),
                                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                                  child: new Row(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Button_with_icon(
                                        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF7CB342),
                                        textColor: Colors.white,
                                        textButton: "Continuer",
                                        onPressed: (){
                                          if(_formKey.currentState.validate()){
                                            print("say l3adab");
                                          }
                                        },
                                        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  )
                         ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )),
              ),
            )
        ),
      );
```

Comment: is all widgets are in any scroll area ?

Comment: User SafeArea then Scaffold finally SingleChildScrollView

Comment: do you tried 'resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false' ?

Comment: Benjith Kizhisseri what do you mean by all widgets in scroll area ? I have used the property resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true, and the problem still appear,   Santosh Anand  I have use what you said and it doesnt work.

Comment: yes, I have had this problem before, but now it kind of different little bit.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was only of using an expanded inside my form, so I have removed and removed the height and width that I have given to my container :

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
            body: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Center (
                child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        gradient: LinearGradient(
                            begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                            end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                            colors: [const Color(0xFF3023AE), const Color(0xFFC86DD7)])),
                    child: Form(
                      key: _formKey,
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 70.0, bottom: 20.0),
                            child: Text(
                              "C'est parti !",
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32, color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
                            child: Container(
                                width: width_textFormField + 15.0,
                                child: Text(
                                  " Avant de commencer, sache que pour utiliser pleinement ta BanKids tu devras demander à tes parents de s'inscrire pour te débloquer toutes les fonctionnalités",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 14,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                )),
                          ),
                          Container(
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Container(
                                    child: Text(
                                      "Client Bank ?",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          color: Colors.white),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Container(
                                      child: Row(
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Text(
                                            "Oui",
                                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                          ),
                                          Radio(
                                            value: 1,
                                            activeColor: Colors.white,
                                            groupValue: _grpVal,
                                            onChanged: _handleRadioValueChange1,
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      )),
                                  Container(
                                      child: Row(
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Text(
                                            "Non",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                color: Colors.white),
                                          ),
                                          Radio(
                                            activeColor: Colors.white,
                                            value: 2,
                                            groupValue: _grpVal,
                                            onChanged: _handleRadioValueChange1,
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      )),
                                ],
                              )),
                          Container(
                            child: Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                customizedTextFormField(
                                    hintText: "Nom",
                                    width: width_textFormField + 10.0,
                                    txtColor: Colors.black),
                                customizedTextFormField(
                                    hintText: "Prénom",
                                    width: width_textFormField + 10.0,
                                    txtColor: Colors.black),
                                customizedTextFormField(
                                    hintText: "Date de Naissance",
                                    width: width_textFormField + 10.0,
                                    txtColor: Colors.black),
                                customizedTextFormField(
                                    hintText: "CIN",
                                    width: width_textFormField + 10.0,
                                    txtColor: Colors.black),
                                customizedTextFormField(
                                    hintText: "Email",
                                    width: width_textFormField + 10.0,
                                    txtColor: Colors.black)
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
                            child: Container(
                              width: width_textFormField,
                              child: Row(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Checkbox(
                                    checkColor: Color(0xFF3023AE),
                                    value: isCheck,
                                    activeColor: Colors.white,
                                    onChanged: _handleCheckBox,
                                  ),
                                  Expanded(
                                    child: Text(
                                      "En continuant l'inscription, je déclare accepter ces conditions d'utilisations ",
                                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          //************ next work
                         Container(
                                  width: 200,
                                  height: 60,
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0,bottom: 8.0),
                                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                                  child: new Row(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Button_with_icon(
                                        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF7CB342),
                                        textColor: Colors.white,
                                        textButton: "Continuer",
                                        onPressed: (){
                                          if(_formKey.currentState.validate()){
                                            print("say l3adab");
                                          }
                                        },
                                        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  )
                         ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )),
              ),
            )
        ),
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

put a column child on singlechildscrollview then create a row for each form element, and put those in expanded widget

```
SingleChildScrollView(
          physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          child: Material(
            elevation: 0,
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Form(
                        onChanged: () {
                          _tcFormKey.currentState.validate();
                          if (_tcController.text.length != 11) {
                            setState(() {
                              tcValidated = false;
                            });
                          }
                        },
                        key: _tcFormKey,
                        child: TextFormField(
                          controller: _tcController,
                          maxLength: 11,
                          inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                            WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
                          ],
                          validator: (String value) {
                            if (value.isEmpty) {
                              return 'Zorunlu alan';
                            }
                            if (value.length != 11) {
                              return 'Kimlik numarası 11 haneli olmalıdır';
                            }
                            if (value.length == 11 && !Functions.validateTC(value.toString())) {
                              return 'Hatalı TC. Kimlik No';
                            } else {
                              setState(() {
                                tcValidated = true;
                              });
                            }
                          },
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(),
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            counterText: '',
                            suffixIcon: tcValidated
                                ? Icon(
                                    Icons.check,
                                    color: Colors.green,
                                  )
                                : Text(''),
                            labelText: 'TC Kimlik No',
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 1),
                            ),
                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black26, width: 1),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 12,
                      ),
                      Form(
                        onChanged: () {
                          _uavtFormKey.currentState.validate();
                        },
                        key: _uavtFormKey,
                        child: TextFormField(
                          controller: _uavtController,
                          maxLength: 11,
                          inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
                          validator: (String value) {
                            if (value.isEmpty) {
                              return 'Zorunlu alan';
                            }
                          },
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(),
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'UAVT Adres Kodu',
                            suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.location_on),
                            counterText: '',
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 1),
                            ),
                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black26, width: 1),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 12,
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Expanded(
                            child: Form(
                              onChanged: () {
                                _adFormKey.currentState.validate();
                              },
                              key: _adFormKey,
                              child: TextFormField(
                                controller: _adController,
                                maxLength: 64,
                                validator: (String value) {
                                  if (value.isEmpty) {
                                    return 'Zorunlu alan';
                                  }
                                },
                                inputFormatters: [
                                  WhitelistingTextInputFormatter(
                                    RegExp("[a-zA-ZĞğÜüÖöŞşçÇİı]"),
                                  ),
                                ],
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  labelText: 'Ad',
                                  counterText: '',
                                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                                      color: Colors.blue,
                                      width: 1,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                                      color: Colors.black26,
                                      width: 1,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 8,
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: Form(
                              onChanged: () {
                                _soyadFormKey.currentState.validate();
                              },
                              key: _soyadFormKey,
                              child: TextFormField(
                                controller: _soyadController,
                                maxLength: 64,
                                validator: (String value) {
                                  if (value.isEmpty) {
                                    return 'Zorunlu alan';
                                  }
                                },
                                inputFormatters: [
                                  WhitelistingTextInputFormatter(
                                    RegExp("[a-zA-ZĞğÜüÖöŞşçÇİı]"),
                                  ),
                                ],
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  labelText: 'Soyad',
                                  counterText: '',
                                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                                      color: Colors.blue,
                                      width: 1,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                                      color: Colors.black26,
                                      width: 1,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 12,
                      ),
                      Form(
                        onChanged: () {
                          _telFormKey.currentState.validate();
                        },
                        key: _telFormKey,
                        child: TextFormField(
                          controller: _telController,
                          maxLength: 10,
                          validator: (String val) {
                            if (val.isEmpty) {
                              return 'Zorunlu alan';
                            }
                          },
                          inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                            WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
                          ],
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(),
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            errorStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                            hintText: '10 Haneli Telefon Numarası',
                            labelText: 'Telefon Numarası',
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black38),
                            suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.phone_iphone),
                            counterText: '',
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color: Colors.blue,
                                width: 1,
                              ),
                            ),
                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color: Colors.black26,
                                width: 1,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 12,
                      ),
                      OutlineButton(
                        highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                        splashColor: Colors.blue.shade50,
                        shape: BeveledRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2)),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: !emptyDateError ? Colors.black26 : Colors.red),
                        onPressed: () {
                          selectedBDate = '';
                          DatePicker.showDatePicker(context,
                              showTitleActions: true,
                              minTime: DateTime(1910, 1, 1),
                              maxTime: DateTime.now(),
                              onChanged: (date) {}, onConfirm: (date) {
                            int y = int.parse(DateFormat.y().format(date));
                            int m = int.parse(DateFormat.M().format(date));
                            int d = int.parse(DateFormat.d().format(date));
                            setState(() {
                              selectedBDate = '$y-$m-$d';
                              emptyDateError = false;
                            });
                            print('confirm $date');
                          }, currentTime: DateTime.now(), locale: LocaleType.tr);
                        },
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 2, right: 2, top: 16, bottom: 16),
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Expanded(
                                child: Row(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Icon(Icons.calendar_today, size: 16,),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 2),
                                      child: Text(
                                        ' Doğum Tarihi',
                                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              selectedBDate != ''
                                  ? Expanded(
                                      child: Align(
                                        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                                        child: Text('$selectedBDate'),
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  : emptyDateError
                                      ? Expanded(
                                          child: Align(
                                            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                                            child: Text(
                                              'Zorunlu Alan',
                                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        )
                                      : Container(),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 12,
                      ),
                      Form(
                        onChanged: () {
                          _mailFormKey.currentState.validate();
                        },
                        key: _mailFormKey,
                        child: TextFormField(
                          controller: _mailController,
                          validator: (String val) {
                            if (val.isEmpty) {
                              return 'Zorunlu alan';
                            }
                            if(!Functions.isEmail(val)){
                              return 'Geçerli bir mail adresi belirtiniz';
                            }
                          },
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.mail_outline),
                            labelText: 'Mail Adresi',
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 1),
                            ),
                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black26, width: 1),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 12,
                      ),
                      Material(
                        elevation: 8,
                        shadowColor: Colors.green,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                        color: Colors.green,
                        child: InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                            if (_tcController.text != '' &&
                                _uavtController.text != '' &&
                                _adController.text != '' &&
                                _soyadController.text != '' &&
                                _telController.text != '' &&
                                _mailController.text != '' &&
                                selectedBDate != '' &&
                                Functions.validateTC(_tcController.text)) {
                              _tcFormKey.currentState.validate();
                              _uavtFormKey.currentState.validate();
                              _adFormKey.currentState.validate();
                              _soyadFormKey.currentState.validate();
                              _telFormKey.currentState.validate();
                              _mailFormKey.currentState.validate();
                              print(_telController.text.length);
                              var oprt = _telController.text.trim().split(' ')[0];
                              oprt = oprt.replaceAll('(', '');
                              oprt = oprt.replaceAll(')', '');
                              print(oprt);
                              _pageController.nextPage(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300), curve: Curves.ease);
                            } else {
                              if (selectedBDate == '') {
                                setState(() {
                                  emptyDateError = true;
                                });
                              }
                              _tcFormKey.currentState.validate();
                              _uavtFormKey.currentState.validate();
                              _adFormKey.currentState.validate();
                              _soyadFormKey.currentState.validate();
                              _telFormKey.currentState.validate();
                              _mailFormKey.currentState.validate();
                            }
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            width: double.infinity,
                            height: 48,
                            child: Center(
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Text(
                                    'İlerle ',
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
                                  ),
                                  Icon(
                                    Icons.arrow_forward,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: I did it and only I see black screen.